# Matching Array value in Dataweave in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to match specific values from payload and return only the matched array value using dataweave expression.

Input:

```
name: QA
```

Payload:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#driveList",
 "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9FV7TFuXfzyGg-txFqJWTa2oDXcgJ3ULdaNmst8",
 "drives": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AKrgo4Gdm2hzUk9PVA",
   "name": "Dev"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AGymmOhxiCGwUk9PVA",
   "name": "EHS Safety - Public"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AAD3jo6D8PX-Uk9PVA",
   "name": "Job Master folder"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AI1WUfEk8cWkUk9PVA",
   "name": "MSTemplates"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
   "name": "QA"
  }
 ]
}
```

Expected output should be like
output:

```
{
   "kind": "drive#drive",
   "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
   "name": "QA"
  }
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following dataweave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == 'QA')
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "drive#drive",
    "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
    "name": "QA"
  }
]
```

Note that the resulting payload will be an array of "drives" items.